# RC constant in a coaxial cable

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

i have a problem with understanding a certain aspect of calculating the RC constant in a coaxial cable.

Given the reistance in the inner wire, and the outer wire, and given the capacitance. These values are obtained by measurements with meters and probes. 
The RC you get for adding the two reistances and multiplying by the capacitance of the cable is twice the one you get from measurements on a screen. I understand that it has to be divided by two somewhere, and intuitively it makes sense to use the average resistance of the inner and outer wire, but I can't explain why. Is this correct?

If it is correct is it because the charges travel equally on both sides so the RC constant is dependent on both the reistances in equal degree and therefore the average reistance is the correct one? Or has it something to do with the layout of the circuit?

Answer (score -1):

The question can not be answered as stated. Coaxial cable is LC not RC. For example the properties of a vacuum are l = 1.2 u Henry by C 9 p Farad. This would make the propagation speed in a vacuum c or 300,000,000 meters per second and the impedance Z = 370 ohms. Does this help?